# curvycorners and jquery validate plugin - form focus issue

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using "jQuery validation plug-in 1.7" for a page with form fields. The trouble is that the entire from is inside a rounded box created by using "CurvyCorners" plug-in. Since the error messages in my case appear below the form fields, the page size increases on appearance of each error message.

I  am using 'curvyCorners.redraw();' on blur of each form element to achieve the page re-size. but every time it resizes the form fields loose focus and I am unable to tab properly in IE7 and below.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please be specific about your error ?

And Try [DD Roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/) instead of curvy corners.

Comment: The page is a .jsp page, the js files are loaded from a different file altogether. I can not alter the script inclusion.  

To make it more simple. I need to find out how to return focus to the next element(form field) in the correct tabbing order if on each 'blur' you are using curvycorner.redraw(). 
Curvycorner makes form fields loose focus.

Comment: Modified code in plugin
  element: function(element ) {
   element = this.clean( element );
   this.lastElement = element;
   this.prepareElement( element );
   this.currentElements = $(element);
   var result = this.check( element );
   if ( result ) {
    delete this.invalid[element.name];
   } else {
    this.invalid[element.name] = true;
   }
   if ( !this.numberOfInvalids() ) {
    // Hide error containers on last error
    this.toHide = this.toHide.add( this.containers );
   }
   this.showErrors();
  curvyCorners.redraw(); 
   return result;
  },